# NSinteger value from NSUserDefaults is always 0

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

Here is my problem:

In a UITableViewController I want to save the index of the selected cell and this is done in didSelectRowAtIndexPath with the following code

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setInteger:indexPath.row forKey:@"myUniqueIdentifier"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

The value is saved correctly but when the user returns to this UITableViewController I want the table to scroll to this cell - sounds trivial but when I retrieve the NSInteger from NSUserDefaults it is always 0!?

I fetch the value with this code in viewWillAppear:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger scrollToIndex = [defaults integerForKey:@"myUniqueIdentifier"];
```

I'm not sure if it is of importance but navigating from the view (when a cell is pressed) and back to my UITableViewController is done via segue.

Thanks!

Comment: The value of indexPath.row is right just after you save on defaults?

Comment: You can try to print the NSUserDefaults to check if you saved correctly. `If the specified key does not exist, this method returns 0.` From Apple Document.

Comment: The value is not saved - I found out that didSelectRow... is never called since the navigation is controlled by another delegate. 

I accidentally thought the value was saved but the NSLog statement was in the view navigated to. The value of the cell I kept selecting was the same as the value in the new view :/

Lesson taught! Thanks!